# Typescript: object is possibly null reported in a comparison expression

Tags: typescript

I'm getting a TS18047 on a comparison where the false result of null comparison is a desired outcome.

so, basically:

```
const a: number | null = null;
if (a >= 250) { /* will not execute because result of comparison is false */ }
```

this is what I want. and this code also worked before I introduced typescript.

I know I could just do a null check, but there's like ten branches comparing this variable against various numbers.

Only the final `else` processes the actual null value.

Do I actually have to check for null or is it possible for me to wiggle out of this?

Comment: Why don't you just check for `null` in the first if condition...?

Comment: If you have like branches, check for `null` _first_., not on the final _else_. Otherwise you will have to check before each comparison. This is exactly what TypeScript is for, making sure you cannot accidentally make type errors. You _can_ wiggle out of it (`a! >= 250` tells TypeScript it is impossible for `a` to be `null` at this point, and that it should shut up), but you really, really shouldn't, unless you know for a fact `a` cannot be `null`, despite the declaration and the lack of the check.

Comment: @Amadan: this should be an answer. It's better explained than Sean's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this should technically work because you can't compare something that's null to a number because it will always be false, so you need to null check it first.

```
if (a && a >= 250) {
      // do something

 }
```

This will also work but it's not best practice because it defeats the purpose of typescript

```
    if (a! >= 250) {
      // do something

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `typeof` Method has sometimes worked for me.

```js
if (typeof a == 'number' && a >= 250) {
        //do something 
}
```

Comment: I can see how this could work, but in far more complicated cases than mine.